# Group nodes with xslt and delete same values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i asked this before but i will try to explain my problem more detailed. Im gettin a XML (the acutal one is a lot bigger as my example here) out of a system where users can book rooms. these rooms are used to communicate from one city to another city. 
so if one person wants to book he must book at least 2 rooms. i created a table so other user can see who booked which room on what date/time.

[table](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/excampleebl6qu32zo.jpg) (cant upload images here yet)
as u can see the table is not very clear. it has a lot of same values what is not needed. so what i want is i just one date and time and one name for each booking in one . but rooms has to at least 2 in the same  for a better view.
in my xslt u can also see tried to get a group of nodes in the test

can u help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href= 'testxsl.xsl'?>
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Datum">01.08.2013</Property>
        <Property Name="Von">04:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Bis">06:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Raum">Cologne</Property>
        <Property Name="Gebucht_Von">ExamplePerson 1</Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Datum">01.08.2013</Property>
        <Property Name="Von">04:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Bis">06:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Raum">Munich</Property>
        <Property Name="Gebucht_Von">ExamplePerson 1</Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Datum">01.08.2013</Property>
        <Property Name="Von">08:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Bis">12:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Raum">Beijing </Property>
        <Property Name="Gebucht_Von">ExpamplePerson 2 </Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Datum">01.08.2013</Property>
        <Property Name="Von">08:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Bis">12:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Raum">Munich </Property>
        <Property Name="Gebucht_Von">ExpamplePerson 2 </Property>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Datum">01.08.2013</Property>
        <Property Name="Von">08:30:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Bis">11:00:00</Property>
        <Property Name="Raum">Bombay </Property>
        <Property Name="Gebucht_Von">ExpamplePerson 2 </Property>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

XSLT Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"   encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TABLE border="6pt" align="center" >
            <colgroup>
                <col width="150"/>
                <col width="100" />
                <col width="100" />
                <col width="200"/>
                <col width="500"/>
            </colgroup>
            <TR STYLE="font-size:16pt; background-color:#E4FEFF; color:051956; font-family:Times New      Roman',Times,serif"> <!-- Eine Zeile der Tabelle wird geöffnet -->
                <span />
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>Daten</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>From</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>To</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>Room</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>Bookey by</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <u>
                        <i>test</i>
                    </u>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Objects">
        <xsl:for-each select="Object">
            <TR STYLE="font-size:13pt;  background-color:#E4FEFF;color:051956; font-family:ARIAL">
                <TD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Property[1]/text()"/>
                    <TD>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Property[2]/text()"/>
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Property[3]/text()"/>
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Property[4]/text()"/>
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Property[5]/text()"/>
                        <TD>
                            <xsl:value-of select= "current()/Property[(current()/Property[1]= following:: */Property[1])and
                                (current()/Property[2]= following::  */Property[2])and
                                (current()/Property[3]= following:: */Property[3])and
                                (current()/Property[4]!= following::*/Property[4])and
                            (current()/Property[5]= following:: */Property[5])]"/>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is what i want to output

```
<TABLE border="6pt" align="center">
<colgroup>
    <col width="150">
    <col width="100">
    <col width="100">
    <col width="200">
    <col width="500">
</colgroup>
<TR STYLE="font-size:16pt; background-color:#E4FEFF; color:051956; font-family:Times New Roman',Times,serif"><span></span><TD><u><i>Date</i></u></TD>
    <TD><u><i>From</i></u></TD>
    <TD><u><i>To</i></u></TD>
    <TD><u><i>Room</i></u></TD>
    <TD><u><i>Booked by</i></u></TD>
</TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:13pt;  background-color:#E4FEFF;color:051956; font-family:ARIAL">
    <TD>01.08.2013</TD>
    <TD>04:00:00</TD>
    <TD>06:00:00</TD>
    <TD>Cologne, Munich</TD>
    <TD>ExamplePerson 1</TD>
</TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:13pt;  background-color:#E4FEFF;color:051956; font-family:ARIAL">
    <TD>01.08.2013</TD>
    <TD>08:00:00</TD>
    <TD>12:00:00</TD>
    <TD>Beijing, Munich, Bombay </TD>
    <TD>ExpamplePerson 2 </TD>
    <TD>true</TD>
</TR>
      </TABLE>
```

Comment: Rather than link to a website, which comes with a pop-up ad that obscures the table you are trying to show, could you amend the question to show the HTML you are trying to output in this case? Also, are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, by the way? This looks like a grouping problem, and grouping is handled differently in XSLT 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: i edited it. thank you for the hints. i need to use xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="groups" match="/Objects/Object" use="concat(Property[@Name='Datum'],Property[@Name='Von'],Property[@Name='Bis'],Property[@Name='Gebucht_Von'])" />
<xsl:template match="Objects">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="6pt" align="center">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="150" />
        <col width="100" />
        <col width="100" />
        <col width="200" />
        <col width="500" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr style="font-size: 16pt; background-color: #E4FEFF; color: 051956; font-family: Times New Roman ', Times, serif">
        <span></span>
        <th><u><i>Date</i></u></th>
        <th><u><i>From</i></u></th>
        <th><u><i>To</i></u></th>
        <th><u><i>Room</i></u></th>
        <th><u><i>Booked by</i></u></th>
    </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', concat(Property[@Name='Datum'],Property[@Name='Von'],Property[@Name='Bis'],Property[@Name='Gebucht_Von']))[1])]">
      <tr style="font-size: 13pt; background-color: #E4FEFF; color: 051956; font-family: ARIAL">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Datum']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Von']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Bis']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:for-each select="key('groups', concat(Property[@Name='Datum'],Property[@Name='Von'],Property[@Name='Bis'],Property[@Name='Gebucht_Von']))">
            <xsl:sort select="Property[@Name='Raum']" />
            <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Raum']" /><xsl:if test="position() != last()" ><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='Gebucht_Von']"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**
[image: XSLT Ouput]

*Note: I updated one of the values of the original input to London to make sure groups where working correctly.*